# Is there a better way than PHP include()

Tags: include

My sites include large segments of data via php's `include()`. This has worked well but I'm building a CMS and ran into an issue...

When I load the page to be edited, the included file doesn't print. I'm sure this is a relative path issue but the question is: What's the best way to deal with this?

*I'm using TinyMCE and it puts all of the PHP into `<!---->` comments anyway, so I may be in big trouble here (I need to keep the PHP `header()`).*

I'm thinking that I will have to just place the included data directly into the page so it doesn't get lost when loaded into the editor. I can probably move the `header()` into a higher document and have it change with variables, but before I do...

**Is there a better way than `include()` to attach large segments of data?**

Comment: This may be a stupid answer, but what about 'require_once()'?

Comment: That puts me in the same boat. Luckily this is limited to just the 'content' of the page, but never the less, it's a problem. I may be forced to use a different inline editor.